# How to use mongoose find to filter by inner arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, find

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fa27539e2b1a10d0fdb82ba"),
    "extra_fields" : [ 
        {
            "tag" : "alias",
            "value" : "thealias"
        }, 
        {
            "tag" : "name",
            "value" : "nobody"
        },
    ]
}
```

This is the object I'm referring to, for example, I need to query all the objects which have a tag="alias" in the extra_fields array of each object. how can I achieve this with MongoDB? Any help would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Please check this,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fa1b8ee30caf0655a64104a"),
    "status" : true,
    "extra_fields" : [ 
        {
            "tag" : "alias",
            "value" : "hes"
        }, 
        {
            "linked_collection_id" : "5fa1946a3ef5864410728f1f",
            "linked_master_id" : [ 
                "5fa19884dae0ba587c891d9a"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "linked_collection_id" : "5f7d68861d5a43b422b12c6d",
            "linked_master_id" : [ 
                "5f7d6c3b629ab057b67fa789"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to know how can I retrieve objects which has linked_collection_id='abc' AND linked_master_id contains 'xyz'. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need `"extra_fields.tag": "alias"` to compare the field and the result.

The query is quite simple:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "extra_fields.tag": "alias"
})
```

In this way, every document with, at least, one 'tag' field with value 'alias' will be returned.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yOPg_5RrThy)

Edit:

To find by multiple fields you can use this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "extra_fields.linked_collection_id": "abc",
  "extra_fields.linked_master_id": "xyz"
})
```

Comment: Hello again, I've updated the post a bit to find another need, can you check it out too. really appreciate.